# Strange fixed positioning not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Open this page : 
http://themeliberty.ir/Urbanier/
If you resize your browser to >1000px , You'll see the scrollbar , 
If you scroll down , You'll find that arrows are not fixed, 
i want them to scroll with page and be fixed.
Also , when I give " Position:fixed; " to style , they are not fixed and also it conflicts some CSS rules.
I also tried some jQuery and CSS Plugins to make them fixed , 
But They didn't.
What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows are inside a container, so they are fixed inside this container. The scrollbar that shows up belongs to this container (not to the body), so the arrows scroll with it. Move the arrows outside of `div.scroll` and they should be fixed relative to the viewport.